# How to add dtd file inside jrxml file instead of giving as url in eclipse

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, excel, jasper-reports

I am using jasper report for exporting to pdf and excel sheets. Here is few lines of xml code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE jasperReport PUBLIC "-//JasperReports//DTD Report Design//EN" 
"http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/dtds/jasperreport.dtd">
<jasperReport name="PDFReport" pageWidth="975">
```

Instead of using this url "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/dtds/jasperreport.dtd" how to add this dtd file into my eclipse project. Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To use local DTD files you need to add XML Catalogs into Eclipse as below.

Open up the "XML Catalog" dialog by:

`Windows -> Preferences -> XML -> XML Catalog`

Then set the Location and Key to match with your DTD.

Location = [JAR-Path]!/[DTD-Path]

Key = "-//JasperReports//DTD Report Design//EN"

As an example, refer to [Hibernate example here](http://www.digizol.com/2013/11/eclipse-local-dtd-hibernate-example.html).